# user Login web service required using prestashop api

Tags: api, authentication, prestashop

I am working on prestashop web services for my android app, i searched a lot in google, but i did not find proper document/proper explanation. Can any one please guide me how to do user login/authentication using prestashop web services?.

Comment: Just in case : i'm facing a similar issue with a browser-side call to the API and tumble uppon this question via Google. I'm thinking about adding some api endpoints that answer user-logged-only informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the PrestaShop webservices and filter with email and password like below:

http://localhost/api/customers/?filter[email]=test@prestashop.com&filter[password]=19910794b7c0b413e80f58298a8d8300

Comment: I see many answers like this but anyone who can access the auth key, which is basically not hidden,  would have access to all the site's customers details. This solution is really not secure. Accessing a list of customers in this way should be done from a server, not a client.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a call to the customer endpoint filtering by the customer's email. The result would have a "passwd" field, which is a hashed password which could either be md5 or bcrypt since Prestashop supports both. You can then hash the customer's password input and compare with the "passwd" field in the response. If the length of the "passwd" field is 32 (md5), you'll need parameter _COOKIE_KEY_ set in /app/config/parameters.php as a salt to generate your hash;

Make the call like this https://yourprestashopurl.com/api/customers?filter[email]=email@email.com&display=full

**For md5 (if passwd is 32 characters long):**
$hash = md5(_COOKIE_KEY_ . $input_password);
You can then compare $hash with passwd

**For bcrypt (if passwd is 60 characters long):**
Option 1:
$verify = password_verify($input_password, passwd);
You can accept $input_password when this returns true, otherwise $input_password is invalid

Option 2:
$hash = password_hash($input_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
You can then compare $hash with passwd

Note: [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) are both built-in php functions since PHP 5.5.0

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still searching for this answer:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET["email"]) && isset($_GET["password"]))
    {
        $email =  $_GET["email"];
        $password = $_GET["password"];

        $COOKIE_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

        $jsonurl = "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@example.com/api/customers?filter[email]=".$email."&display=[passwd]&output_format=JSON";
        $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
        $json_a = json_decode($json, true);

        $loopone = $json_a['customers'];
        $looptwo = $loopone[0];
        $loopthree = $looptwo['passwd'];

        $ZCpassword = md5($COOKIE_KEY . $password);

        if (strcmp($loopthree, $ZCpassword) == 0) {
            echo "sucess";
        } else {
             echo "fail";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error";
    }

?>
```